# Swagger jaxrs Doclet custom annotations not generating output

Tags: swagger, doclet

I'm using the very helpful swagger-jaxrs-doclet tool from teamcarma to generate the json files necessary to feed into a swagger-ui front end for documenting my RESTful services.

An issue that I'm having is that the custom annotations (e.g. @bodyType ) described in the doclet documentation do not appear to be picked up by the doclet at time of documentation generation.

Taking an example from the doclet documentation itself, I may have a service endpoint documented as such:

```
/**
 * @inputType fixtures.inputtype.Data2
 */
@POST
@Path("/postData2b")
public Response postData2b(@HeaderParam("X-forwarded-for") String xFwd, @QueryParam("p1") int p1, Data1 data) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I would expect the `@inputType` annotation to be used for supplying the body model.

Unfortunately, the annotation is completely ignored.

Has anyone had a similar problem working with swagger-jaxrs-doclet? How did you over come it?